# Ajax,PHP,MYSQL interaction

Tags: php, ajax

I have a page2 that is linked from page1.page1 sends a unique job id to page2.page2 has ajax code as shown below.In this page2,i have a select that takes in the number of applicants to be called for an interview.it fetches this number from page3 according to the number of points achieved by each applicant.How will I fetch data for applicants according to the passed job id?I think my problem is passing parameters in ajax.Any help please?
thus is my code but isnt working.I get error in page2,An uknown index jobid.

```
<?php $getid =$_GET['jobid'];?>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script>
function showSuccess(str,$getid) {

    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = 
        function  () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("POST","interview.php?q="+str);


        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
  echo $getid;
  ?>
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<form>

    <?php 

     include('includes/conn.php'); 
     $row="SELECT * FROM jobs";  
     $query=mysqli_query($conn,$row) or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
      $ref=$row['id'];
     }          

echo '<select name="names" onchange="showSuccess(this.value'.$getid.')" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>

  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="35">35</option>
  <option value="40">40</option>
  <option value="45">45</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="55">55</option>
  <option value="60">60</option>
  <option value="65">65</option>
  <option value="70">70</option>
  <option value="75">75</option>
  <option value="80">80</option>
  <option value="85">85</option>
  <option value="90">90</option>
  <option value="95">95</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
  </select>';
  ?>
  <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" name="number" placeholder='Enter the no of candidates' required>-->
</form>
</div>
<br>
<div id="txtHint" class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"><b>The candidates</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php $q = intval($_GET['q']);
?>
<?php $getid = intval($_POST['$getid']);?>

<?php
include('includes/conn.php');
$row="SELECT  idNo,id,name,jobTitle,SUM(points) AS total FROM shortlist WHERE job='$getid' GROUP BY id ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT $q";
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$row) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
  echo $row['name'];
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Can you show the code in `interview.php`?

Comment: <?php $q = intval($_GET['q']);
?>
<?php $getid = intval($_POST['$getid']);?>

<?php
include('includes/conn.php');


$row="SELECT  idNo,id,name,jobTitle,SUM(points) AS total FROM shortlist WHERE job='$getid' GROUP BY id ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT $q";
$query=mysqli_query($conn,$row) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
  echo $row['name'];
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>

Comment: Please put code inside the question with formatting,how do you expect us to read this?

Comment: Am sorry.I have pasted in the question

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the value in `POST` data

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","interview.php?q="+str);
```

But in the 3rd file you are using,

```
<?php $getid = intval($_POST['$getid']);
?>
```

You are not sending `$getid` in the POST/GET parameters.

Comment: I have edited and now am getting the following notices:Notice: Undefined index: q in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\jobportal\admin\admin\interview.php on line 1
and 
Notice: Undefined index: $getid in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\jobportal\admin\admin\interview.php on line 3

Comment: Since you are passing data in URL ,try using `$_GET` everywhere ,and you should fetch all data.

Comment: @user3752159 You are not sending `$getid'` and accessing it in `$_POST['$getid']`.

Comment: Now am getting 'Notice: Undefined index: $getid in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\jobportal\admin\admin\interview.php on line 3' after using $_GET everywhere

Comment: @user3752159 Yes,you will get that,JUst check my answer now,you are not sending the `$getid` in AJAX call,but fetching the value,hence the error.Pass that value also through AJAX

Comment: Thanks @varun.Let me play with it

Comment: it hasnt worked well so far.the $getid is not passed to the interview.php page.only variable q is the one passed.how can I post more than one variable?

Comment: @user3752159 Do it this way, `xmlhttp.open("POST","interview.php?q="+str+"&$getid="+getidvalue);`

Comment: it worked with this:var data = "q="+str+"&job_id="+(job_id);